# How to implement a permanent redirect from an old invisible page to a new one in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, redirect, visibility, display, window.location

I have an old webpage, which should be redirected to another one. The redirection works, but the user can see the old webpage for some seconds. How can I make the old page invisible?

I tried to use the code

```
window.location.href.indexOf('old_page').style.visibility = "none";
```

But it doesn't work.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            if (window.location.href.indexOf('old_page')) {
                window.location.replace('new_page');                }
        });
    </script>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try adding the following line, just above your if condition `$("body").css("display","none")`

Comment: No need to put it in `$(function(){` ... put it in script tag at top of head since you don't need the rest of page to load. These sorts of redirects are better managed server side

Comment: @Hackerman: After redirecting I get an empty page. What did I do wrong?       <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){ 
                $("body").css("display","none")
                if (window.location.href.indexOf('old_page') > -1) {
                    window.location.replace('new_page');                }
            });
        </script>

Comment: Do you have that code on the new page, too? You shouldn't use `display none` on the new page.

Comment: The two pages are in the same system/server and I can only code in one JavaScript field.

Comment: I tried it this way, but without any success. Any ideas? <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){ 
                if (window.location.href.indexOf('old page') > -1) .css('display','block') {
                    window.location.replace('new page');                }
            });
        </script>